# How to vary the substituion string in regular expressions with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been learning about regular expressions and I've been attempting this problem - to turn multiple date formats into standard date formats. Specifically in this case, it would be turning YYYY/MM/DD -> DD/MM/YYYY. I have a list of dates for this problem to test and I've shortened it to what you see below.

```py
datesToTest = '''
    20/05/2002
    2004/06/25
    2005/05/09
    2003/08/04
'''
```

What I want to come out is:

```
20/05/2002
25/06/2004
09/05/2005
04/08/2003
```

I wrote a regular expression object that looks for dates in the format YYYY/MM/DD.

```py
#The regular expression that I am using.
findWrongDateFormRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    \d{4}
    .
    \d{1,2}
    .
    \d{1,2}
)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

I wrote code to then correct the dates that are in the wrong format, and add them to an array, which is called dateArray.

dateArray ends up looking like this: `['25/06/2004', '09/05/2005', '04/08/2003']`

So now what I want to do is to replace each wrong date with the correct, ordered date from the list.
I wrote this to test something:
`fixedDates = findWrongDateFormRegex.sub(str(dateArray[0]), datesToTest)`
This replaces all the dates I want to replace, but with only 25/06/2004. Is there a way that I can go about varying the replace string with each change?

Apologies for the convulted question, and thank you for your time.

Comment: can you elaborate your function `findWrongDateFormReger.sub()`? Otherwise we have no way of knowing what it does and how to advise.

Comment: Ah sorry, that's my bad. The regex object name was meant to be ```findWrongDateFormRegex``` - I've edited it correctly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First do

```
fwdf = re.compile(r'(\d{4}).(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2})')
```

to get numbered groups. Then you can do

```
datestring = "2004/06/25"
fwdf.sub(r"\3/\2/\1", datestring)
# '25/06/2004'
```

to reorder those groups. The `\3`, `\2`, `\n`, etc. in regex have a special meaning when used in `re.sub` - they refer to the third/second/`n`th captured group respectively, allowing you to reinsert them as you need.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot